# Why are the Nicene and Dedication Creeds so different?

Tags: trinity, persons-of-the-trinity, non-trinitarian, nicene-creed, arianism

The Nicene and Dedication Councils were attended by more or less the same people and were only 16 years apart (325 vs 341) but resulted in opposing creeds. The Nicene Creed is pro-Sabellian but the Dedication Creed is anti-Sabellian. What made the difference?

### More or less the same people

The Dedication Council was a Council of the Eastern Church and the Nicene Council was almost exclusively Eastern:

> At Nicaea, the delegates were “drawn almost entirely from the eastern
> half of the empire” (LA, 19).
>
> “Very few Western bishops took the trouble to attend the Council (of
> Nicaea). The Eastern Church was always the pioneer and leader in
> theological movements in the early Church. It is well known that
> Hilary, for instance, never really understood the Arian Controversy
> till he reached the East as a result of being exiled. The Westerners
> at the Council represented a tiny minority.” (RH, 170)
>
> The Nicene Council “was overwhelmingly Eastern, and only represented
> the Western Church in a meagre way.” (RH, 156)

### The Nicene Creed is pro-Sabellian.

> “If we are to take the creed N at its face value, the theology of
> Eustathius and Marcellus was the theology which triumphed at Nicaea.
> That creed admits the possibility of only one ousia and one
> hypostasis. This was the hallmark of the theology of these two men.”
> (RH, 235) [Eustathius and Marcellus were the two main Sabellians
> who attended in Nicene Council.]
>
> “The Creed of Nicaea of 325 … ultimately confounded the confusion
> because its use of the words ousia and hypostasis was so ambiguous as
> to suggest that the Fathers of Nicaea had fallen into Sabellianism, a
> view recognized as a heresy even at that period.” ([Hanson’s Lecture](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/hanson/#325))
>
> “In the controversies which erupted over Eustathius of Antioch and
> Marcellus after Nicaea, both thought their theologies faithful to
> Nicaea—and they had good grounds for so assuming. Both were
> influential at the council, and Nicaea’s lapidary formulations were
> never intended to rule out their theological idiosyncrasies.” (LA, 99)
>
> After Nicaea, the Creed was associated “with the theology of Marcellus
> of Ancyra. … The language of that creed seemed to offer no
> prophylactic (prevention) against Marcellan doctrine, and increasingly
> came to be seen as implying such doctrine.” (LA, 96, 97)
>
> “To many the creed seemed strongly to favour the unitarian tendency
> among these existing trajectories.” (LA, 431) [Ayres uses the term
> “unitarian” to refer to Sabellianism. For example: “A great deal of
> controversy was caused in the years after the council by some
> supporters of Nicaea whose theology had strongly unitarian tendencies.
> Chief among these was Marcellus of Ancyra.” (LA, 431))
>
> “Simonetti estimates the Nicene Council as a temporary alliance for
> the defeat of Arianism between the tradition of Alexandria led by
> Alexander and ‘Asiatic’ circles (i.e. Eustathius, Marcellus) whose
> thought was at the opposite pole to that of Arius. … Alexander …
> accepted virtual Sabellianism in order to ensure the defeat of
> Arianism. … The ‘Asiatics’ … were able to include in N a hint of
> opposition to the three hypostases theory.” (RH, 171)
>
> It is not “an openly Sabellian creed.” “It is going too far to say
> that N is a clearly Sabellian document. … It is exceeding the evidence
> to represent the Council as a total victory for the anti-Origenist
> opponents of the doctrine of three hypostases. It was more like a
> drawn battle.” (RH, 172) Ayres says that his conclusions are close to
> Hanson’s in this regard (LA, 92).
>
> The Dedication Creed of 431 “represents the nearest approach we can
> make to discovering the views of the ordinary educated Eastern bishop
> who was no admirer of the extreme views of Arius but who had been
> shocked and disturbed by **the apparent Sabellianism of Nicaea**.” (RH,
> 290)

### The Dedication Creed is anti-Seballian.

While Sabellianism asserts only one single hypostasis, meaning one single rational capacity or mind, the Dedication Creed explicitly asserts that the trinity is “three in hypostasis but one in agreement (συμφωνία)” (LA, 118). “One in agreement” indicates the existence of three distinct ‘Minds’.

> The Dedication Creed’s “chief bête noire [the thing that it
> particularly dislikes] is Sabellianism, the denial of a distinction
> between the three within the Godhead.” (RH, 287)
>
> The Dedication creed is “strongly anti-Sabellian.” (RH, 287)
>
> “The creed has a clear anti-Sabellian and anti-Marcellan thrust.” (LA,
> 119)

LA = Ayres, Lewis, Nicaea and its Legacy, An Approach to Fourth-Century Trinitarian Theology, 2004

RH = Hanson RPC, The Search for the Christian Doctrine of God: The Arian Controversy, 318-381. 1988

Comment: The nicene creed is pro-Sabellian? Says some book from the 1980s? How about you quote the actual text of the creed and contemporary theologians to back up that point?

Comment: "Eustathius was condemned for Sabellianism. His insistence that there is only one distinct reality (hypostasis) in the Godhead, and his confusion about distinguishing Father, Son and Holy Spirit laid him open to such a charge." - Hanson, Richard Patrick Crosland (1988). The Search for the Christian Doctrine of God: The Arian Controversy, 318-381. T. & T. Clark. ISBN 978-0-567-09485-8. The Nicene Creed is not pro-sabellianism.

Comment: A better question might be about the use of *homoousion* in the Nicene Creed in 325 despite its previous use by Sabellius to reject a distinction of hypostases, and the failure to use *homoousion* in the Creeds of the 341 Synod of Antioch despite that synod's continued rejection of aspects of Arianism. The reality seems to be that for about 25 years there was little mention of the *homoousion* formula, though that changed when Athanasius wrote *De Decretis*.

Comment: @eques I am using the world experts on th Arian controversy; RPC Hanson, Lewis Ayres, Rowan Williams. If you are aware of any other books by 'contemporary' experts, I would love to hear that. But an expert is somebody who studies the ancient documents themselves; not a person like me who studies the work of such experts.
With respect to your comment that I must quote the actual text of the creed, I most certainly can do that. See - https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/homoousion/

Comment: @KenGraham If the Nicene Creed is nie pro-Sabellian, how would you describe it? It certainly is not anti-Sabellian. It is open to a Sabellian reading. By Sabellian I mean that the trinity is one single rational capacity (literally one single mind and will). As I study the Controversy, starting with the second-century Logos-theologists, Monarchianists, Sabellianists, Eusebians, pro-Nicenes, and Basil of Caesarea vs Athanasius, the question always is whether the training is one or three rational capacities.

Comment: @Henry Yes, you are right. I have already posted that question. See - https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/97673/why-was-homoousios-not-mentioned-for-20-years-after-nicaea/97749#97749 Athanasius brought homoousios back into the Controversy in the mid 350s, not to defend the Nicene Creed, but to defend his own theology. See my answer to that question - https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/97915/56029

Comment: @Andries My point stands. You may be quoting the "experts" but we aren't here to do your homework. A person like you shouldn't just trust other experts without looking at the texts themselves. "the trinity is one single rational capacity" do Sabellians use the term "trinity"? What about "begotten" "proceed" etc in the creed? Those don't describe single rational in the Sabellian (non-personal way)

Comment: @eques I am afraid it is beyond my capacity to study the primary documents. People like Hanson and Ayres spent their entire careers doing that. But I do my best to identify the 'experts' and I read their books. For example, I asked my local university. But once you read enough, you can see who cite who.

Comment: @eques I do not know whether Sabellians use the term 'trinity'. But I did not use that word because Sabellians use it. I used it as a shorthand for 'Father, Son, and Holy Spirit'. I used it with a small t, indication a group of three, in contrast to Trinity, which refers to the Triune God.

Comment: @eques You propose that terms such as "begotten" and "proceed" do not indicate a single rational faculty. I agree. But the big question is what homoousios meant. That was the main controversial issue and I concluded that it was understood as Sabellian before, during, and after Nicaea. https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/homoousion/

Comment: @Andries and yet if a Sabellian understanding of homoousious is not Trinitarian both those statements cannot be entirely true since it would conflict with the intention of begotten and procession identifying subsistent relations in the one substance

Comment: @eques You need to distinguish between the Trinity doctrine and the Nicene Creed. The fourth century was a period of evolution in doctrine. See https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/intro-arian-controversy/ 
In the traditional Trinity, the Trinity is one Being with one single rational faculty. In other words, the Son is not a distinct rational faculty. The Son, therefore, is not a distinct 'Person' in the normal sense of the word 'person'. So, I struggle a bit with your statement that "a Sabellian understanding of homoousious is not Trinitarian."

Comment: @Andries It's not beyond you. You're definitely at the level where you need to do more engagement with primary sources. If you don't feel equipped, then I suggest formal study might help!

Comment: @Andries kindly refrain from telling me distinctions I need to make when you don't understand the things you are demanding I distinguish. Trinitarian theology doesn't call the Son a different rational faculty. There is one Divine Intellect and Will in Trinitarian theology. My point about homoousion is that either Sabellians and Trinitarians would use the term in approximately the same way hence the creed wouldn't rule out Sabellian understanding of the term (other content might suggest a particular interpretation)

Comment: @Andries (cont) or the two schools mean something incompatible with each other which means the Creed must be either Sabellian or Trinitarian. Yet you indicate that begotten or proceeded do not indicate "a single rational faculty" (Note I said they don't describe a single rational Sabellian way). Hence if the creed uses begotten and proceeded for the Son and Holy Spirit, it cannot be meaning it in a Sabellian way. Using "trinity" as shorthand for the 3 names is unnecessarily confusing (trinity = triad, triple specifically related to being "three each")

Comment: @eques The 325-creed does not say anything about the Spirit proceeding. That's a 381 addition. I think we must describe the impact of the Creed in terms of what is different from the previous creeds. For example, the Creed begins by identifying the Father as the One God, which was the standard opening for all creeds. Trinitarians prefer to read quickly past that and go to 'very God of very God', which is new. In the same way, homoousos is new. If identify the theology that drove the Nicene Creed by what is new, 'begotten' doesn't count.

Comment: @eques You took exception to the fact that I said that you must distinguish between the Nicene Creed and pro-Nicene Theology. That is what the top trinitarian experts say. “By ‘pro-Nicene’ I mean those theologies, appearing from the 360s to the 380s … of how the Nicene creed should be understood. … These theologies build closely on and adapt themes found earlier in the century, but none is identical with any original ‘Nicene’ theology apparent in the 320s or 330s.” (LA, 6) See the introduction of Ayres' book: https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/lewis-ayres-nicaea-and-its-legacy/

Comment: @eques I take note with joy of your statement that Sabellians and Trinitarians understand homoousios in the same way. That confirms my suspicion that the traditional Trinity doctrine is a variation of Sabellianism. In both, the Father, Son, and Spirit are but one single rational faculty. (CuriousDanny, I have now which from Centre of Consciousness to Rational Faculty. I think that describes the concept better.) However, there are different Trinity doctrines. See https://trinities.org/blog/podcast-370-dr-steven-nemess-formal-challenge-to-trinity-theories/

Comment: @Andries no, I took exception to you insisting on a distinction which you do not understand yourself since you refer to Persons as "distinct rational faculties". If you can't be bothered to read the original texts and the theologians of the day, then you shouldn't tell us what distinctions to make. I didn't say Sabellians and Trinitarians use the same homoousian; I posited 2 distinct possibilities that would have to be the case in relation to your claim. I did not specifically state which one appears to be true, so hold your joy.

Comment: @Andries The claim that Trinitarianism is a variant of Sabellianism is nearly meaningless. The entire contention of Arianism vs Trinitarianism vs Sabellianism and so on is a reconciliation of the Scripture text around Father, Son and Holy Spirit and one God. The Trinitarianism is like  Sabellianism in one way, but it's like Arianism in another. The same pattern occurs in the other theological controversies of the day -- oscillation between different extreme positions until resolving in the correct position.

Comment: @eques "A distinction which you do not understand yourself since you refer to Persons as 'distinct rational faculties'." I wonder what you mean by that. The Persons of the Trinity, in the traditional Trinity doctrine, are not distinct rational faculties. So, 'Person' in that context is misleading. Did you think I did not know that?

Comment: @eques Theology is not my main interest. My main thesis is that the church never decided to become Trinitarian. What happened was that, in the Roman Empire, the emperors were the final arbiters in doctrinal disputes and that they (particularly Theodosius in the year 380) made the Trinitarian faction of Christianity the state religion of the Roman Empire and ruthlessly exterminated all opposition. The Arian Controversy began when persecution subsided and ended when persecution resumed. The church of the Roman Empire, (the Roman Church) became the church of the Middle Ages.

Comment: @eques When I began to study the Arian Controversy, I did read much theology. But eventually I concluded that the core issue was whether the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit are one or three rational faculties. One rational faculty theology began with the second-century Monarchians and continued in the third century with the Sabellians and people such as Dionysius of Rome and Paul of Samosata. In the fourth century, Alexander, Athanasius and the Sabellians continued it but was opposed by Basil of Caesarea. But, eventually, emperor Theodosius decided that one rational faculty is the way to go.

Comment: @Andries what tripped me up is you stating you agreed with me that begotten implies the Father and Son is not a "single rational faculty" when I didn't use the term "rational faculty" that seemed to imply that you identified "person" with "rational faculty" which is not Trinitarian. My point was that begotten implied a non-Sabellian view in the Creed since it posits a real distinction between Father and Son yet in a single rational substance (homoousion). Yes the core issue is what do the terms Father, Son, Holy Spirit mean in relation to God, then what does Christ mean vs the Son.

Comment: @Andries of course the Church didn't decide to become Trinitarian. That would imply it selected theologies from equal options. The Church had to sort through the text and refine its understanding through the controversies of the day.

Comment: @Andries but again, this would be more apparent if you would read Athansius, Augustine, Cyprian of Carthage, Gregory of Nysa, Boethius, et al yourself

Comment: @eques How many minds (rational faculties, centers of consciousness, selves) do you believe the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit have, one or three? Asked differently, is it impossible for them to disagree on something?

Comment: What I believe isn't the direct point. Trinitarian theology espouses one Intellect and will in God, yet 3 Persons.

Comment: @eques Ah! The standard but misleading language - the standard smokescreen of those who have something to hide. I was expecting a bit more bravery. But I hope that you at least can see the importance of focusing on the number of intellectual faculties? If you said one, you would be in violation of the Bible, and if you said three you would be in violation of the Establishment.

Comment: @Andries if you are going to sincerely seek knowledge, you should avoid ascribing "hiding" or other misdeeds to your interlocutors. One will/intellect is certainly not against Scripture.

Comment: @Andries further it is a bit rich for you to accuse the standard terminology as being "misleading" and a "smokescreen of those who have something to hide" when you adamantly refuse to read the early texts where those terms are discussed and defined. I have read those texts. If this is how you continue to engage, I will refuse.

Answer (score -3):

The reason for the difference in the two creeds is that Emperor Constantine was present at the Nicene Council and manipulated the outcome:

**Legalized Christianity** - Religious freedom did not exist in the Roman Empire. The emperors decided which religions are allowed. After three centuries of persecution by the Roman authorities, Emperor Constantine legalized Christianity in the year 313.

**Letter to Alexander and Arius** - Even before Constantine understood the matter, he wrote to Alexander and Arius to stop their quarreling. This shows that he got involved in this dispute, not because of a desire for right doctrine, but because he could not afford a split in the church.

**Council in Antioch** - A few months before the Council of Nicaea, an anti-Arian Council was held in Antioch, consisting mainly of people who sympathized with Alexander. It provisionally excommunicated Eusebius of Caesarea, the most respected theologian of that time, who also supported Arius against Alexander. Since Constantine’s religious advisor (Ossius) chaired this meeting, it was approved by Constantine, which means that, even before Nicaea, Constantine had taken Alexander’s part.

**Called the Council** - Constantine called the Nicene Council. Nobody asked him to do it. He did it on his own initiative for his own purposes. It was Constantine’s meeting in his capacity as emperor.

**The General Council** - In fact, Constantine invented the concept of a general council for the church. The church never before had a meeting of representatives from all parts of the empire. Neither did it have the ability to call such a council. Only the emperor was able to call such a meeting.

**Emperor's Motive** - As his letter to Arius and Alexander shows, Constantine did not call the Nicene Council because of a concern about right doctrine. He called the Council because a split in the church could also split the empire. Constantine, therefore, invented and called the general council as a means of managing the church in the interest of the empire.

**Chairperson** - To ensure that the Nicene Council remains under his control, the emperor appointed his religious advisor (Ossius) as chairperson. Ossius acted as Constantine’s agent.

**Took Alexander’s Part** – It is often correctly stated that Arius had considerable support. The Nicene Creed, however, was constructed as a deliberately anti-Arian document and was approved by all of the 250-300 delegates, except 2. Why? Arius’ support was not really support for his theology. It was a vote AGAINST Alexander’s theology. Alexander, however, was victorious at Nicaea because the emperor had taken his part. If Constantine had not taken Alexander’s part, the meeting might have condemned Alexander; not Arius.

**Homoousios** - At the time, the term homoousios (same substance) seemed especially objectionable to many people because it was associated with Sabellianism, is not a Biblical term, was not part of the standard Christian language, but was borrowed from pagan philosophy. (See - [Objections to Homoousios](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/homoousios-important/#obje)) Constantine’s decisive influence on the Council and on the Creed, therefore, is particularly revealed by the fact that he was able to force the inclusion of the word homoousios. He personally proposed, explained, and enforced the key term homoousios.

**Reconcile** – Although Constantine took Alexander’s part and insisted on Homoousios, his ultimate goal was to reconcile the quarreling parties. For example, he explained homoousios in such a way that even the Eusebians ([the so-called Arians](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/little-writings/)) were able to accept the term. He paid all expenses and surrounded the delegates with honor.

**Exile** - The bishops knew, if they do not accept the Creed, that they would lose their jobs and be exiled to a different part of the empire. How many bishops would have voted against the Nicene Creed if exile was not hanging over their heads?

**Exile and Restore** - In the Roman Empire, the standard penalty for bishops for deviant teachings was exile but only the emperor was able to exile and restore bishops.

**Enforced Nicaea** - After Nicaea, Constantine issued a number of letters attempting to enforce the Council’s decisions.

**Conclusion** - “Constantine took part in the Council of Nicaea and ensured that it reached the kind of conclusion which he thought best.” (RH, 850)

The above is a summary of the article - [Constantine's role in the Council of Nicaea](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/council-of-nicaea/)

The Nicene Council was attended almost exclusively by delegates from the Eastern Church. Since the Dedication Council was a council of the Eastern Church, the Dedication Creed shows how the Nicene Creed would have read if Constantine had not manipulated the outcome.